# How to get the version of visual studio used to develop a software?

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I am having .net code and am looking for a way to find out which visual studio version was used to last build that software.

Is there any way I can get this looking at the source code files please?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the latest version (VS 2017) and port the project. You will be asked in the beginning when you open the solution (.sln) file. It will probably work just fine (there are some rare exceptions when it's not).

By opening the projectName.sln file. It will say what version it was last compiled with. Like this:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
# Visual Studio 14
VisualStudioVersion = 14.0.25420.1
MinimumVisualStudioVersion = 10.0.40219.1
```

You can have a look here for what version you have
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#History